# Entity Framework, Bound Context and DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, entity-framework-5

I am trying to create bounded context using EF and a edmx file. At the beginning all entities are in the same edmx file and then I split the model in another project and I change the Dbset and I use IDbSets instead. I created other edmx file and I am trying to use a table/tables that are in the other edmx. Of course when I run the custom tool (right click on the edmx file, run custom tool) the tt file removes the table/Idbset from one place to another. What do you guys do?  How about if you need a context with few tables and you do not want some tables that are related to the one that you add to that context. Hopefully someone understand my question?

Comment: Not exactly and answer so i'll put is as a comment - but in my point of view DDD has nothing to do with repositories/database/tables/orms. It took me a long time to understand this, and, not unlike you, I was getting into trouble with tools trying to make them do what I thought DDD was. In my view the essence of DDD is iteratively defining bounding contexts and their aggregates. Even if you don't actually do it, it helps thinking about persitentce in terms of event sourcing as it forces you to clearly define the boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was reading more about this and I believe that doing it with Code First is the way that can be approach in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create multiple edmx(s) with only the tables you need? For example ABC.edmx have three tables A, B & C. The three entities that you generate through T4 belong to a bounded context ABC. You can create another DEF.edmx having the tables D,E & F. The entities D,E & F belong to the bounded context DEF.